# CPU Pinned above 95% when BDC profile import (Full and Incremental)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sharepoint, moss

We have daily full profile imports using BDC connection. In that duration, CPU spiking very high. That team is concern. How to resolve this issue. Please anybody have any idea on this? Please share with me.

It is physical box with 16 GB RAM. CPU is spiking all the way till its complete BDC job (not like only initially). I have 85000 records to check and update user profile information. So When ever BDC starts CPU spiking crazy.

***CPU spike in SQL server not SharePoint server***

Comment: I think the term "spiking" is misused here. "Pinned above 95%" is more like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really isn't much you can do since the User Profile Service imports are in sealed code which, unlike custom code, cannot be throttled.  The UPS should not spike the entire server unless the server only has 1 CPU.
My best advice is to schedule the import to un off hours e.g. 2 AM.